# Печать на термопринтере

Tags: php, печать, cups

У меня есть принтер jp-5890k. Я печатаю через этот плагин - [ссылка](https://github.com/smalot/cups-ipp)

Все хорошо, кроме одного - я не могу настройки авто размер печати. То есть, у меня печатает только стандартные размеры. Как это можно побороть?